# Use of $avg function within MongoDB aggregation framework does not appear to alter returned value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database, nosql

I'm sure there's something relatively obvious that I'm missing. Basically, these two queries return the exact same result despite the use of the $avg and $sum:1 functions, from what I understand the first query should return an average of the previously grouped row count?

```
db.bbservicedata.aggregate( 
{ 
   $match:{"accesstime" : {"$gte" : ISODate('2012-02-09T01:45:32.962Z') }}
},  

{
   $match:{"requestModel.serviceName" : "ContentItem"}},    
{

   $unwind: "$requestModel.methodParams.ContentItemLoggingListModel.items"},

{ 

$group: {
 _id:{
   myYear:{$year:"$accesstime"},
   myMonth:{$month:"$accesstime"},
   myDay:{$dayOfMonth:"$accesstime"}}, 
   count:{$sum:1}}}, 
{ 
$group: {
 _id: {
   year: "$_id.myYear",
   month: "$_id.myMonth",
   day: "$_id.myDay"}, 
   averagecount : {$avg : "$count"}}},  

   //{averagecount : {$sum: "$count"}}}***, -- Returns the same result*

 {$sort: {averagecount:-1}} 
);
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `$group` is using the same `_id` terms as the first one, so you'll always have a single doc per `_id`.  In that situation `$avg` is always going to equal `$sum`.